# What does __ prefix before some kernel api's convey?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

Why do some function calls in kernel specially have this prefix `__`

example: `__init initialization(void)`

is `__init` a macro?

What does this convey? Are these a special class of function calls inside the kernel or do they resemble any assembly function body present inside? What actually are they trying to represent?

Comment: This has been answered at the Stack Overflow site [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832114/what-does-init-mean-in-the-linux-kernel-code)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Code_cynic, the double underscore means that is is reserved (the same for keywords with one underscore followed by a capital letter):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10687114/2915175

The explanation of the `__init` macro can be found here and it expands to a `__attribute__`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8832166/2915175

Answer (score -2):

It means it's a system-reserved name.that means it is reserve for implementation.